# Randomly increase values of a row (binary), with specific conditions

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a data set like this:

```
A   B C D E F G
12  1 0 0 0 0 0
Hey 0 1 0 0 0 0
No  0 0 0 0 0 1 
Yes 0 0 0 0 1 0
```

I want to build an scenario, what will happen if a COLUMN has 10% more YES (yes = 1). But, in my scenario, this should be done with 3 columns at the same time.

So: let's say that the rows of interest are where B=1 or C=1 or D=1. If one of the columns is equal to 1, that is fine. But I want to (randomly) make 10% of the remaining rows (where B=0 & C=0 & D=0) into a 1 (and of course, if we give them (the randomly 10% of the remaining rows) a 1, then the other columns should be all 0 (except column A)).

Sorry, really had a hard time to explain this problem. Hopefully it is clear.

The result should be something like this (it is not representing the 10% since the example is too small).

```
A   B C D E F G
12  1 0 0 0 0 0
Hey 0 1 0 0 0 0
No  0 0 0 0 0 1 
Yes 0 1 0 0 0 0
```

where you can see that "Yes" is randomly assigned as C=1, and its original value is set back to 0.

Comment: I don't get the 10% part. Do you want a random 1 in row YES where other cols have a 1 ?

Comment: Hi Andre, thanks for reaching out. From ALL the remaining rows (where B&C&D ==0), I want randomly make 10% as 1 (so the 1 should appear in column B,C or D).

Comment: clear! what is a row where `B&C&D ==0` already has a 1. Does that already BELONG/ADDUP to the 10% rule.

Comment: All of the remaining data  should have a 1 (in column E,F or G). For the 10%, the 1 should be transformed into a 0, and in column (B,C or D.. randomly) to a 1. Sorry, hope that I explained it clear :-)

Comment: I think you can extend my solution to your needs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this is what you want:

data:

```
df1<-
structure(list(A = c("12", "Hey", "No", "Yes"), B = c(1L, 0L, 
0L, 0L), C = c(0L, 1L, 0L, 0L), D = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), E = c(0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L), F = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 1L), G = c(0L, 0L, 1L, 0L)), row.names = c(NA, 
-4L), class = "data.frame")
```

code:

```
m <- `rownames<-`(df1[,-1],df1[,1])  # make your life simple, add character col as rownames

percentage = .5   # choose any percentage you like from 0 to 1, .1 for 10%
amountOf1  = floor(percentage * ncol(m)) # get the amount of ones based on percentage

IND <- which(rowSums(m[,1:3]) == 0)  # get those rows having B, C, D with 0

for(i in IND) {
    m[i,] = sample(rep(1:0,c(amountOf1,ncol(m)-amountOf1)) )
}
```

result: (now 50% are 1 in rows where B,C,D is 0)

```
#    B C D E F G
#12  1 0 0 0 0 0
#Hey 0 1 0 0 0 0
#No  1 0 0 0 1 1
#Yes 1 0 1 0 0 1
```